# Django REST Framework : How to define nested viewsets and get more explicit lookup_field names?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, lookup, django-rest-viewsets

**Context**

I have two viewsets, with their own routers to automatically generate the URLs from them :

- ModelAViewset
- ModelBViewset

For now, only the ModelAViewset details can be access through the following URL :

`{root_url}/model-a/<slug>`

With '`<slug>`' being the ModelA 'slug' field, as a lookup_field.

I am trying to figure out a way to build a route towards ModelBViewset detail as follows :  `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_pk>`

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to use a more explicit lookup_field value, dynamically based on the model name ? Like this : `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>`

*Note : To keep it simple in the model, I would rather like to leave the 'slug' field name of ModelA as is*

2. Based on Viewsets and Routers, is there a way to access the ModelBViewset details through a multi lookup_fields ? With an URL like :

   `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_pk>`

Thanks, by advance

Comment: [`DRF nested routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) can help you achieve the `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_pk>`

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I saw that yesterday. But there can't seem to be possible to use 'slug' instead of 'pk' as a lookup_field

Comment: In `ModelAViewset`, you can set `lookup_field = 'slug'` as described in the [`docs`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) to use the model field `slug` instead of `pk`

Comment: And then when you use nested routers, you can do the same for `ModelBViewset`, so you can end up with `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_slug>`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `lookup_field` on the model, the reference to this field will only work on the model where the `lookup_field` was defined.

That way, to work like this `{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_pk>` you'll have to override `ModelBViewset` `get_object` function
or you can follow [this steps](https://linuxtut.com/en/fe8d4470a05895a70748/).

Another way to reference the `slug` field is to create it in the model itself as `primary_key` like this:

```
class ModelA(model.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=60,
        unique=True,
        help_text="Define primary_key=true.",
        blank=True,
        primary_key=True
    )
```

That way, every time you're referencing an object in this model or other models like you want (`{root_url}/model-a/<model_a_slug>/model-b/<model_b_pk>`), you'll need to use the `slug` field and not `id`. **The `id` field no longer exists.**